# react-three-fiber: How to capture events ANYWHERE in <Canvas />?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to create a 3D experience using `react-three-fiber` where the user can interact with any part of the 3D canvas, including points on the canvas that both (a) intersect an object, and (b) where there is nothing intersecting the ray at all.

This means I can't use the pointer events abstractions built into `<mesh />` etc., as those pointer events ONLY capture points that intersect objects.

I tried attaching handlers to the `<Canvas onMouseDown={...} />`, however I'm unable to access the THREE internals from there as the `event` passed by `onMouseDown` does not contain them, and the `useThree` hook must be deeper in the tree to access the THREE react context.

So I also tried creating a component nested inside `<Canvas />` (see below) where I'd be able to use the `useThree` hook:

```
<Canvas>
  <MouseHandler>
    ...
    <mesh />
    ...
  </MouseHandler>
</Canvas>

export function MouseHandler({ children }) {
   const { Camera } = useThree()
   return <Html><div onMouseDown={...}>{children}</div></Html>
}
```

...but then react-three-fiber complains that I have THREE objects inside HTML objects.

Anyone have any suggestions on how else I might be able to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't feel like a common enough use case that `react-three-fiber` would ever support, so what I ended up doing was hack it like this, using React Refs to yank a "pointer" to the three objects I needed from deeper into the tree.

```js
const threeRef = useRef()

<MouseHandler threeRef={threeRef}>
  <Canvas>
    <ThreeConnect threeRef={threeRef}>
      ...
      <mesh />
      ...
    </ThreeConnect>
  </Canvas>
</MouseHandler>

...

export function MouseHandler({ threeRef, children }) {
   const { Camera } = threeRef.current
   return <Html><div onMouseDown={...}>{children}</div></Html>
}

...

export default function ThreeConnect({ children, threeRef }) {
  const { scene, camera } = useThree()

  useEffect(() => {
    threeRef.current = {
      ...threeRef.current,
      camera,
      scene,
    }
  }, [scene, camera])

  return <>{children}</>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach behavior to the `onPointerMissed` prop of a mesh object, and the attached handler will fire whenever an event is raised on that canvas that does not intersect with that mesh.

The handler will receive a PointerEvent, having a pointerId property, though it will not have an eventObject property.

So if you could somehow afford to have an outer mesh around everything, and attach behavior to its opPointerMissed prop, then you'd handle any click that wasn't caught by any of the objects in the scene.

Answer (score -1):

You need add onMouseDown in `<mesh>` for capture points that intersect objects.
And add onPointerMissed in `<Canvas>` for capture nothing intersecting.